# Cloth Separating from Hooks

Tags: cloth-simulation

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to simulate a strip of cloth being pulled around by hooks. The cloth does not stay completely attached to the hooks, but lags behind them a bit. Each vertex at each end of the plane is attached to its own hook. I've made sure that my hook modifiers are above the cloth modifier. I've also tried applying a soft body simulation to the plane instead of cloth and I get a very similar result. Does anyone know why the cloth doesn't stay completely attached to the hooks?

Comment: Hello. Try subdividing or increasing the physics resolution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I discovered that the vertex weights of my pinned vertices was set at 50%. I bumped it up to 100% and everything seems to be working now.